# A minor confusion in C

Tags: c, pointers

i am new to C programming .... so there are mere chances you will find the question damn easy

```
char *ii;
int i=54;

ii=(char *)&i;
```

for what purpose is there (char *) and is using char pointer for int address is helpful in some way ? and is it will be exactly the same as with using int pointer ?

Comment: @TavianBarnes: Isn't aliasing by char pointer a exception which doesn't  violate the rule?

Comment: @TavianBarnes - the exception for `char *` is noted in the answer you linked to

Comment: @Zaibis: Yes, it is allowed.  Made clear right there on the page Tavian linked to.

Comment: Yep, looks like I need more coffee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question seems to assume that using a `char*` to hold the address of an integer has a valid purpose.

It does not, and is not a proper way to code.

There are cases where the data that a pointer points to is not known at compile time. And that can lead to code similar to this. But, as a general rule, it is not useful and should be avoided.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no valid purpose?  Especially older APIs often used `char*` as the "pointer to generic type" instead of `void*`.

Comment: I disagree with the assertion that this has NO valid purpose.  The one that comes to mind immediately is working with other peoples code where the original author didn't understand the purpose of `void *` as an argument to a function that deals with arbitrary bytes (think `memcpy`, `write` for example).  And I'm sure there are reasons you might want to "inline" similar functionality.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The example I gave was the case where the type being pointed to is not known at compile time. I have done stuff like this. But it's a hack, and it serves no valid purpose on its own, although it may serve as a hack for complex scenarios.

Comment: @JonathanWood - So you're saying a large portion of `<string.h>` and `<stdio.h>` are nothing more than a hack with "no valid purpose on its own"?   I hardly think `memcpy` is a complex scenario, and it's one that ALL C programmers should understand how to handle correctly.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland: If a large portion of `<string.h>` declare a `char *` in order to store the address of an integer, then yes. But we both know that's not the case.

Comment: No... but virtually every function in the std library that uses a `void *` as an argument (to which an `int *` can be passed) later casts to `char *`, `unsigned char *` or a derivative type.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland: That is not the same. In the case you're describing, `void *` is used where the type is not known at compile time (as mentioned in my answer). Specifically declaring a `char *` to hold the address of an `int` is *not* the same, and has no valid purpose *on its own*.

Comment: It's also definitely NOT undecided behavior. `(char*)&i` is the address of the first byte of the integer `i`. That's 100% well-defined, 100% valid code. The C standard makes no guarantees as to how things like integers are stored in memory (endiannes and such), but this code is a perfectly valid way to find out, and any compiler that does not compile and run this code successfully is broken.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of [type punning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) in C, and it has some uses (although it is generally not safe).

For example, if you want to look at the binary representation of a particular object, you could do something like

```
unsigned char *bytes = &some_object;
for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof some_object; i++ )
  printf("%02x ", bytes[i] );
```

I'm not sure why someone would want to treat an integer as an array of plain `char`, but I'm sure somebody has a use case.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is a part of C [type casting procedure](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm).

But, to be honest, it is unclear for what reasons you are doing such type cast.